# Incorporating a PHP variable directly into AJAX script without need of form submission

Tags: php, ajax

I am a relative novice and have been unsuccessful in solving an AJAX coding problem, so I thought that I would submit this for your expert help:

**Current Setup: (Date value submitted by form to AJAX script)**

A selected value (which is a date) is submitted from a dropdown form on the main page via the onchange event which calls an Ajax script on that same page which in turn passes the value to a separate PHP file (getuser.php). Getuser.php gets this date value to return information from a MySQL database displaying it in a table. The table from the getuser.php is subsequently displayed back on the main page in a div tag (tab1) as part of a JavaScript “glider”. This works fine in its present form, but it is not what I am ultimately trying to accomplish.

**Desired Setup: (Date value passed to Ajax script from predefined PHP variable on main page load, not from form)**

On loading the main page, the desired date value is already assigned to a PHP variable ($mydate), so no separate form selection of a date or passing this selected form date is needed. All that needs to be done is to automatically pass the PHP variable $mydate to the AJAX script on page load which should incorporate this value into the URL and automatically send it to the getuser.php (on main page load) without having to go through a user defined form selection.

**This is the current AJAX script on the main page (which works fine via the form submit method):**

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("tab1").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("tab1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

**This is the current form on the main page that currently selects the date and passes it to the AJAX script..:**

```
<form>

<SELECT NAME="" onchange="showUser(this.value)">

<option value="">Select a date:</option>

<option value="2012-09-26">2012-09-26</option>

<option value="2012-09-25">2012-09-25</option>

<option value="2012-09-07">2012-09-07</option>

<option value="2012-09-08">2012-09-08</option>

<option value="2012-08-01">2012-08-01</option>

<option value="2012-08-04">2012-08-04</option>

</SELECT>

</form>
```

**..but the current date is already set on main page load in the php variable $mydate, so the form is not needed.**

The secondary page getuser.php gets the value of the passed URL ($q=$_GET["q"];) and uses it to display information from a MySQL database in a table. This table is displayed back on the main page in a div tag (Tab 1) in the form of a separate JavaScript “glider” :

```
<div id="glider"><div class="controls">
<a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a> | 
<a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a> |
<a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a> |
<a href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></div>
<div class="scroller"><div class="content">
<div class="section" id="tab1">Tab 1</div>
<div class="section" id="tab2">Tab 2</div>
<div class="section" id="tab3"><img src=" "  
/></div>
<div class="section" id="tab4">Tab 4</div>
</div></div></div>

<script type="text/JavaScript" charset="utf-8">
        new Glider('glider');
</script>
```

I have tried multiple variations on the AJAX script code trying to get $mydate directly into the AJAX script bypassing the form and for it to automatically function per above, but nothing works. There is probably an easy answer to this, and it may just be syntactical.

Comment: If you already have the value in PHP, why use AJAX to retrieve the value and not just retrieve it directly with PHP and load the table when the page loads?

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try something like this in your PHP file

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
showuser("<?php echo $mydate ?>");
</script>
```